# How to search for random string matches in MYSQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working in a voice recognition algorithm that looks for matches at a DataBase(MySQLi). My problem is that if I recognize something like: Milk Shake, and I have Milkshake at my DB (without white space) then I wont have a Math by using LIKE.

```
WHERE products.status = 1 AND products.product_name LIKE "%'.$key.'%"
```

Is there a way to get a match with Milk Shake and Milkshake at my Database? *delete all white spaces is not an option.

Comment: You can use regexp : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the following statement achieves what you are tying to do.

```
WHERE products.status = 1 AND products.product_name LIKE '%Milk%Shake%';
```